# Async page load in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Im mvc application,there is a some view, data of some portion in view is taking time at the server end, so I need to load the other part of the view first and when the process completes the remaining portion will load.

For this I have create a partial view the partial view action is async and returns a task. But in Mvc 5 I cant use await keyword in view. I sesrch for that mvc 6 is fix this issue.

So now I am loading the partial view by using ajax call. But can I do without ajax call.  Or with c# async programming feature.

Comment: well, how about compiling partial view in controller with async task on thread pool using `Task.Run` and then return the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to perform async operations in controller in top level action - neither view nor child actions can be asynchronous in versions up to ASP.Net MVC5.

Or wait till MVC6 is ready, or if you case allows that use MVC6 now - [vNext](http://www.asp.net/vnext).

Comment: yes, alexei I research for the same but I didnt find any solution for the child action can be async. of cource we need to wait for the vnext stable.Thanks