# best solution for load data dynamic in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, dynamic, partial-views

some data takes 2-3 seconds to load. My idea is to load the page immediately and then insert the data partially into the page. What is the best way to do this with MVC?

```
    public ActionResult WholeSite()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }

    public PartialViewResult PartialSite()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
```

And the part of WholeSite:

```
    <div id="partialContent"> please Wait ... </div>


    @section scripts{
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
               $("#partialContent").load('@Url.Action("PartialSite", "Home")')
            });
        </script>
    }
```

is this the best way? or is there a better solution in MVC (without JQUERY)?

Thanks

Comment: you mean something like this ? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27031359/async-page-load-in-mvc

Comment: you realize you tagged your question with javascript but dont want a solution that uses jquery (which is implemented in javascript)